# ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.distlib.scripts' when I try to install fabric by python pip

Tags: python, pip, fabric

When I run this command on  CentOS4.9, it happens such error. I try to search it in Google but no found. Looks I am the first person meets such issue.

# pip install fabric

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 8, in <module>
load_entry_point('pip==7.0.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-   py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 318, in load_entry_point
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 2221, in load_entry_point
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 1954, in load
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
from pip.index import Link
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 34, in <module>
from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 92, in load_module
raise ImportError("No module named '%s'" % (name,))
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.distlib.scripts'
```

I went to /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/distlib. There is scripts.py file.

Comment: Can you try `pip install --upgrade pip` first and see if that helps?

Comment: Thanks @Bo102010 your reply. But pip-7.0.1 is the newest version of pip.

Comment: What about with `pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall pip`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I install pip for Python 2.6 on OS X?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540825/how-do-i-install-pip-for-python-2-6-on-os-x)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://superuser.com/a/918751/87805), try installing SSL support.

On CentOS:

```
yum install openssl openssl-devel
```

On Debian:

```
apt-get -y install libssl-dev
```

If `libssl-dev` is not present, try: `openssl-dev`.

Comment: Important note here: You will need to uninstall, then reinstall Python after getting openssl. I just tried this and was dismayed to find that pip didn't suddenly work. Only after I recompiled Python with the newly installed `openssl` did it work for me.