# How do I install pip for Python 2.6 on OS X?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.6

I have an OS X system where I need to install a module for python 2.6. Both `pip` and `easy_install-2.6` are failing:

```
# /usr/bin/easy_install-2.6 pip
Searching for pip
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/pip/
Download error: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'pip' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error: unknown url type: https -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for pip
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('pip')
```

Downloading [get_pip.py](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installing.html) and running it with the stock OS X-supplied python 2.6:

```
# python2.6 ./get_pip.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./get_pip.py", line 17868, in <module>
    main()
  File "./get_pip.py", line 162, in main
    bootstrap(tmpdir=tmpdir)
  File "./get_pip.py", line 82, in bootstrap
    import pip
  File "/tmp/tmpVJBvaW/pip.zip/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpVJBvaW/pip.zip/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpVJBvaW/pip.zip/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpVJBvaW/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 34, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmpVJBvaW/pip.zip/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 92, in load_module
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.distlib.scripts'


$ python2.6 --version
Python 2.6.9
```

With python2.7, either method works fine.

Comment: It should be automatically provided when installing Python via `brew`, e.g.: `brew install python`. Alternatively use: `sudo easy_install pip`.

Comment: Try the Homebrew extension, [BrewPip](http://brewformulas.org/BrewPip).

Comment: How about trying to install pip from the source ?  https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pip#downloads

Comment: why do you need to run python 2.6? I would remove python completely and install python from home-brew (which includes pip).

Comment: @kenorb, I had trouble trying to install py2.6 using brew

Comment: @dermen Then find what was the problem installing python using brew and solve it. Run `brew doctor` to see what's the problem is. The most common is the permission thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Download the source file [here](https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/p/pip/pip-7.0.1.tar.gz#md5=5627bb807cf3d898a2eba276685537aa). Then do

```
>> cd ~/Downloads
>> tar -xzvf pip-7.0.1.tar.gz
```

(replacing `~/Downloads` if necessary). Then

```
>> cd pip-7.0.1
>> sudo python2.6 setup.py install
>> cd
```

(the last `cd` is used to leave the build directory). Now you should be able to run

```
>> python2.6 -c 'import pip;print pip.__version__'
7.0.1
```

By default, pip (when installed from source) should be installed into `/usr/local/bin`. To check:

```
>> /usr/local/bin/pip --version
pip 7.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.1-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)
```

Now you can install your favorite packages using

```
>> /usr/local/bin/pip install package
>> python2.6 -c 'import package'
```

If you have conflicting versions of `pip` in `/usr/local/bin` you can try this ridiculous one liner:

```
>> python -c 'import os;dir="/usr/local/bin";[ os.system("echo %s/%s: && %s/%s --version"%(dir,s,dir,s)) for s in os.listdir("/usr/local/bin") if s.startswith("pip")  ]'
/usr/local/bin/pip:
pip 7.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.1-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)
/usr/local/bin/pip2:
pip 7.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.1-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)
/usr/local/bin/pip2.6:
pip 7.0.1 from /Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/pip-7.0.1-py2.6.egg (python 2.6)
```

to find the one linked to py2.6. (in my case they are all the same)

Comment: Following this process seems to throw the same ImportError as mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 3):

By default [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) provides `pip` command via: `brew install python`.

So try installing Python using Homebrew. Try to not use `sudo` when working with `brew`.

To verify which files are installed with your Python package, try:

```
$ brew list python
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/bin/pip
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/bin/pip2
/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.9/bin/pip2.7
...
```

which should consist `pip`.

After installation you should symlink your formula's installed files by:

```
brew link python
```

which should create the right symbolic links (such as `/usr/local/bin/pip` pointing to your `Cellar/python/2.?.?/bin/pip`)

If you've permission issue, you may fix it by:

```
sudo chgrp -R admin /usr/local /Library/Caches/Homebrew
sudo chmod -R g+w /usr/local /Library/Caches/Homebrew
```

and make sure your user is in admin group (`id -Gn $USER`).

Then re-link it again:

```
brew unlink python && brew link python
```

To test dry-run, unlink and run: `brew link -n python` to see links of files which `brew` would link.

After linking is successful, make sure that your PATH system variable have `/usr/local`, if not, add:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

to your `~/.bashrc` file.

If successful, your `pip` should work now.

---

If you don't want to use Homebrew or you have two Pythons installed on your Mac, you can alternatively install it via:

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

---

Your error:

> Download error: unknown url type: https

means that your Python can't handle HTTPS protocol without having SSL support, so try installing: `openssl` package (on Linux either `libssl-dev` or `openssl-devel`).