# Install python 2.6 on Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-2.6

I have to use an API which uses Python 2.6 and am having a very difficult time getting it installed on my mac.  I have downloaded it but figuring out what I am supposed to write in my bash_profile is exceedingly difficult.  For all versions of Python that I have used so far I write

```
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:${PATH}"
export Path
```

in my bash profile.  But I can't do that for python 2.6 because it does not have a bin folder.  Does anyone know what I'm suppoed to write on my bash profile in order to get Python to use version 2.6?

I'm aware that one solution is pyenv but I tried that a long time ago and there were too many modules that I could not install with it so I don't like that program.

I'm also hoping `brew` will work but according to this page
https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/
python 2.6 is no longer available for brew install.  And when I run `brew install python@2.6` no formulae are found.

My current strategy is to try macports so we'll see how that goes.

Comment: You don't really want to use Python 2.6 anymore. Any details about that API?

Comment: Congrats on hitting the cash-cow ;)... Possible solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30540825/how-do-i-install-pip-for-python-2-6-on-os-x

Comment: @Klaus, the API requires Python 2.6.  I know it sounds pathetic, but hey I didn't write the API

Comment: I'd say fix the API. It's going to be less painful than maintaining a Python 2.6 project.

Comment: Yea, I think you're right.  I'm going to try that first. It's only about 100 lines of code.

Comment: I got to the point where I'm getting an HTTP 403 error.  Do you know if it has to be case that it's the website that is to blame for that error or could it possibly be that using Python 3.8 instead of Python 2.6 is to blame since the API was originally written for 2.6?

Comment: Never mind.  I got it.  I already fixed the API and got it working.  I was using the wrong URL.