# Error when using pip to install

Tags: python, pip

Whenever I try to install anything using pip I get the following error:

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade pip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('pip==7.0.3', 'console_scripts', 'pip')()
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 558, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2682, in load_entry_point
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2355, in load
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2361, in resolve
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pip.vcs import git, mercurial, subversion, bazaar  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/vcs/subversion.py", line 9, in <module>
    from pip.index import Link
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/index.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pip.wheel import Wheel, wheel_ext
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 35, in <module>
    from pip._vendor.distlib.scripts import ScriptMaker
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip-7.0.3-py2.7.egg/pip/_vendor/__init__.py", line 92, in load_module
    raise ImportError("No module named '%s'" % (name,))
ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.distlib.scripts'
```

This also happens when I try to upgrade pip, install sphinx or basically any install/upgrade option using pip.

I am running Ubuntu 15.10 and using Python 2.7.10

StackOverflow has said this is a duplicate, and that there is a solution at [ImportError: No module named 'pip._vendor.distlib.scripts' when I try to install fabric by python pip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425152/importerror-no-module-named-pip-vendor-distlib-scripts-when-i-try-to-install) however the recommend solution on this post is not actually a soltuion. It does not solve my issue, nor does it appear to solve the original posters problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named 'pip.\_vendor.distlib.scripts' when I try to install fabric by python pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30425152/importerror-no-module-named-pip-vendor-distlib-scripts-when-i-try-to-install)

Comment: Its not a duplicate as this post is using a different OS.

Comment: Not sure but ... try running the command with `sudo`

Comment: Yes I have tried it with sudo. Same error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade --no-use-wheel pip
```

Comment: Will you please post the output of : sudo pip -v -v -v install --upgrade pip

Comment: Expand on your reasoning for your answer. Give background to help to OP understand the solution beside from giving them a solution. Also "try this" leaves doubt in the answer.